# Image reselect php

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have a table where each row has an image and some text. Currently, when I update the content without selecting an image, the database field for the image gets cleared out. However, I want to keep the old image if there's no image selected.

How can I accomplish this?

As a note, I know that mysql_* functions are deprecated.

```
<?php

include("db/db.php");

$select_db = "select * from aboutus WHERE id=1";
$run_news = mysql_query($select_db);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($run_news)) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $image = $row['image'];
    $content = $row['content'];
}
?>
<div class="box box-primary">
    <div class="box-header with-border">
        <h3 class="box-title">Update About Content</h3>
    </div>
    <!-- /.box-header -->
    <!-- form start -->
    <form role="form" method="post" action="aboutcontent.php?id=1"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="box-body">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputFile">Reselect Image *(H=530px, W=800px)</label>
                <input type="file" name="user_image"  id="exampleInputFile">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label >Content</label><br>
                <textarea name="content" class="tinymce" class="form-control" rows="15"><?php echo $content; ?></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.box-body -->

        <div class="box-footer">
            <button type="submit" name="update" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<?php

include("db/db.php");

// Code for UPDATE button
if (isset($_POST['update'])) {

    $content = $_POST['content'];

    $imgFile = $_FILES['user_image']['name'];
    $tmp_dir = $_FILES['user_image']['tmp_name'];
    $imgSize = $_FILES['user_image']['size'];

    if ($imgFile) {
        $upload_dir = 'images/about/'; // upload directory  
        $imgExt = strtolower(pathinfo($imgFile, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)); // get image extension
        $valid_extensions = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif'); // valid extensions
        $userpic = rand(1000, 1000000) . "." . $imgExt;

        if (in_array($imgExt, $valid_extensions)) {
            if ($imgSize < 5000000) {
                unlink($upload_dir . $row['image']);
                move_uploaded_file($tmp_dir, $upload_dir . $userpic);
            }
            else {
                $errMSG = "Sorry, your file is too large it should be less then 5MB";
            }
        }
        else {
            $errMSG = "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
        }
    }
    else {
        // if no image selected the old image remain as it is.
        $userpic = $row['image']; // old image from database
    }

    // if no error occured, continue ....
    $sql = "UPDATE aboutus SET image='$userpic', content='$content' WHERE id=1";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    if (!$query) {
        die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    else {
        echo "<script>alert('Successfully Updated!!!'); window.location='index.php?aboutcontent'</script>";
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: @Fred-ii- do you have a solution anyway?

Comment: "I know it's deprecated". So why not update it? Right now you're asking us to help you maintain a very insecure script. A script that doesn't just put you at risk, but your users just as well. We're not telling you this stuff because we don't want to help you with your issue. We're telling it because we don't want you to return here later because you've gotten into some serious trouble. You are responsible for your users private data you know. People can sue you and you will be guilty if you didn't do your best to protect that data!

Comment: @icecub thansk for the time you took for writing this short 'essay' for me i can start write this in mysqli or oop as i know it all want to know is where the problem is

Comment: The problem is easy. You're always updating the image field in your database. Instead, simply check if a file was submitted or not before doing the update. `if(!empty($userpic)){ // SQL update here } else { // No file submitted so don't update }`

Comment: @icecub thats all i wanted! Thanks, i don't know why i dint think of that , put this as an answer so i can mark it as accepted

Comment: And yet you still seem to be using them :-(

Comment: @Strawberry using what

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can easily be solved by checking if a file was submitted or not:

```
if(!empty($userpic)){
    // SQL update here
} else {
    // No file submitted so don't update
}
```

The reason you were getting empty mysql fields is because you were updating the field with an empty variable.

Comment: @SaqibMalik Not really. That's just basic stuff, lol. I would recommend you to read and use this class: http://culttt.com/2012/10/01/roll-your-own-pdo-php-class/ It'll take you about 15 mins to understand and use it. And it will make your life a whole lot more easy :)

Comment: [link](https://pastebin.com/S8HrkUfr) already got  it : all i wanted to know how i could do it in mysql

Comment: @SaqibMalik I see. Well I'm glad you've got it worked out now. Good luck and happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Since I can't comment yet, when you submit without an image are you landing in the if or else statement (place a die('some content) in each part) to figure this out. If you are not making it to the else, try:

```
//initialize error message
$errMSG = '';

//this error means 'There is no error, the file uploaded with success'
if($_FILES['user_image']['error'] == 0){
 //rest of logic to get the filename and move files stuff
}
else{
   $userpic = $row['image'];
}

//you dont want to update database if there are errors
if(errMSG = ''{
  $sql = "UPDATE aboutus SET image='$userpic', content='$content' WHERE id=1";
}
```

OR just make two different database calls, one for when you have an image and one for when you dont

```
if($_FILES['user_image']['error'] == 0){
 //rest of logic to get the filename and move files stuff
    //if everything else is true (has filename and correct file size)

   //you dont want to update database if there are errors
   if(errMSG = ''{
      $sql = "UPDATE aboutus SET image='$userpic', content='$content' WHERE id=1";
}
  $sql = "UPDATE aboutus SET image='$userpic', content='$content' WHERE id=1";
}
else{
   $userpic = $row['image'];

  $sql = "UPDATE aboutus SET content='$content' WHERE id=1";
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: still nothing happens

Comment: Add a new answer so I can rate you up so you can then start commenting

Comment: which part of the condition are you making it to? Do you always end up in the if part or the else statement where make image = what the database value is

Comment: thats the whole code. everytime i update the ['content'] i have to reselct the image or the ['image'] filed gets empty in the database

Comment: can you `die(var_dump(_FILES));`  after you if (isset($_POST['update'])) so we can see what is being sent when no photos are selected

Comment: array(1) { ["user_image"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(0) "" ["type"]=> string(0) "" ["tmp_name"]=> string(0) "" ["error"]=> int(4) ["size"]=> int(0) } }

Comment: check out my updates, you also want to check you $errMSG var and not update if it is set;

Comment: this was a very simple question all i had to do this what is said in the [accepted] answer

Comment: thaks for your time anyways